Whats element can I change to replace UIStackView to show 2 images row
I use a vertical UIStackView to show images in my iOS app just like the image below

But now I need to change that behaviour and show two images per row just like the example below.

What UI component can I use to do that ?
ps: I use ViewCode to create that screen, but I suppose it's not necessary to publish the code because I just want to know which component will be better to complete this task

You have a vertical UIStackView. You want a vertical stack view that contains 2 side-by-side images, right? So create a vertical stack view that contains horizontal stack views. Then you'll have vertical grouping of rows.
Edit:
If you want a true grid of images, you should look at using a UICollectionView instead.
There are pros and cons to each approach. A vertical stack view containing horizontal stack views is simple and easy to build, and each row is a discrete object in the UI (if that's what you want.)
A collection view is very powerful, but also complex and kind of confusing to manage. (If you haven't used one before, be prepared for a pretty steep learning curve. It makes a UITableView seem simple by comparison). It will let you set up a true grid of UI elements (or just about any other arrangement that you want.

Your suggestion is something that I was trying to avoid because I will need a lot of horizontal stackViews. But maybe is the simplest way to solve the question.

@fabiobh Why do you want to avoid "a lot of horizontal stack views"?

I think if there is a UI element that can put all images in a grid, it will be easier to create and manipulate images. Is there something like that?

There are pros and cons to the various approaches. If you want your rows to act as single objects, rows of horizontal stack views would be a good choice. If you want your objects to act like a grid then a UICollectionView might be a better choice. It's a more complex control and harder to understand, but offers a lot of options.

By the way, you should add the iOS tag to your question since it is iOS specific.

@DuncanC I will try to use the UICollectionView. I added the iOS tag to the question now.
